# Sending docker build contexts

Tags: docker

My directory structure is as follows

```
  cassandra
      Dockerfile
      downloads
          225M file
```

I am inside cassandra directory. My build command is

```
   docker build -t image_cassandra .
```

I know that it will send all the contents in `.` current directory. So it takes so much of time to send this 225M file. I need this file in my Dockerfile.

```
  Add downloads/ /tmp/
```

I want to avoid this much of delay. And I know that, we cannot use `../` in docker ADD command. So is there any way to reduce the size of build context and have this ADD command.

This file is not part of web. So i cannot use any `apt-get wget` statements. Or isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate the project into two docker images, a big one that changes infrequently, and a small one that you can change fast.

```
Project1/
    Dockerfile
    bigfile

Project2/
    Dockerfile
```

Project1/Dockerfile would look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get install cassandra
ADD bigfile
```

Then if you build it and tag it with `docker build -t project1 Project1`, you can use the result in Project2/Dockerfile:

```
FROM project1
RUN fast configuration commands
```

Comment: Nice Idea Man :) You are good. Let me wait for some other solutions other than two docker files. If no other feasible solutions, you are the best